# jQuery Masked Input leading zero(s)

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm using [jQuery Masked Input](http://plugins.jquery.com/maskedinput/) to mask to a four-digit dollar amount with a decimal separator but no delimiter ($). So, just like this: xx.xx

Here's my code example: `$('input[id^="myMaskedInput"]').mask("?99.99");`

That works great for four-digit numbers 1234 => 12.34 and so on.

My problem is when I enter a one, two, or three-digit number. For example, I need 123 to mask to 01.23, not 12.30. I.e., I need a leading zero or zeros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to use (or polyfill with) [padStart()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart).

From MDN documentation:

> The padStart() method pads the current string with another string (repeated, if needed) so that the resulting string reaches the given length. The padding is applied from the start (left) of the current string.

Below is an example given your criteria using a minor modification to the polyfill method. The code will add the leading zeros you are looking for on page load. However, due to how jQuery masking, this code snippet will not replace zeros with values as you type.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('input[id^="myMaskedInput"]').val( function(index, value) {
    return padStart(value, 4, "0");
  }).mask("?99.99");

});

function padStart(value, targetLength,padString) {
  targetLength = targetLength>>0; //floor if number or convert non-number to 0;
  padString    = String(padString || ' ');

  if (value.length > targetLength) {
    return String(value);
  }
  else {
    targetLength = targetLength-value.length;

    if (targetLength > padString.length) {
      padString += padString.repeat(targetLength/padString.length); //append to original to ensure we are longer than needed
    }

    return padString.slice(0,targetLength) + String(value);
  }
}
```